Build problem from aasitnikov/fat-aar-android plugin
I use this one https://github.com/aasitnikov/fat-aar-android (latest 1.4.1) with AGP 8.5.0 and Gradle 8.7 to build aar library. However, I get error "Resource and asset merger: Duplicate resources" on debug/assets/Some_Default_Model.tflite
I add this to build.gradle
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    embed ("some") { transitive = true }
    ...
}

and this in gradle.properties, based on Known Defects or Issues in https://github.com/aasitnikov/fat-aar-androidand
android.disableResourceValidation=true

Any solution to fix the error?
